# Deletion in a linked list

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

> Qn) Given only a pointer to a node to be deleted in a singly linked list, how do 
>   you delete it?

I am trying to delete the last element i.e., 1 but the `else` part goes into an infinite 
loop printing garbage values.

[Original link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-only-a-pointer-to-a-node-to-be-deleted-in-a-singly-linked-list-how-do-you-delete-it/).

```
int main()
{
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    push(&head, 1);
    push(&head, 4);
    push(&head, 6);
    push(&head, 8);
    print(head);
    del_p(head->next->next->next);
    cout << endl;
    print(head);
    return 0;
}

void del_p(struct Node* current)
{
    struct Node* temp;
    if (current->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = current->next;
        current->data = temp->data;
        current->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        free(current);
        current = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what did you find out during your own debugging attempts?

Comment: @MartinJames It gives garbage values but as pointed out by 0x499602D2 it works fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` branch of your function tries to reassign `current` to `NULL`. This is problematic because `current` is a *local copy* of the pointer passed in. That is, you can't modify the value of the original pointer.

This is why you are receiving garbage, because you're accessing a node whose memory has already been deallocated.

You either need a double pointer, or preferably a reference to the node:

```
void del_p(struct Node*& current)
```

Comment: 0x499602D2 void del_p(struct Node* current) works fine for all the values except the end why is it so? And by using reference we work directly with the value and not with the address so how is it solving this issue of original pointer can u pls clarify?  U said the point where i am accessing a node the memory has already been deallocated where did i deallocate it? Pls clarify

Comment: @Rooney10 The code works for all values but the end when not using a reference because inside the `if` branch you're not modifying the pointer itself but its members. The `else` branch does `current = NULL` which changes a *copy* of the pointer. Dereferencing a pointer  (with `*` or `->`) returns a reference, but current is not a reference (unless you used `&` of course). Also, you deallocated the memory with `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in the node to be deleted and the head node then you can loop until you find the node prior to the node to be deleted. You then need to point the prior node to the node that is pointed to by the node to be deleted and then you can free the node you want to delete.

```
void delete(struct Node* to_delete, struct Node* head)
{
    // check if node to be deleted is the head
    if (to_delete == head)
    {
        head = to_delete->next;
        return;
    }

    // make a local copy of the head just in case as to not alter it
    struct Node* tempHead = head;
    while(tempHead->next != to_delete)
    {
       tempHead = tempHead->next;
    }
    tempHead->next = to_delete->next;
    free(to_delete);
}
```

Just as a disclaimer I haven't tested this code, but conceptually it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The typical algorithm for deleting a node on a linked list would follow the next steps:

- Get a `temp` pointer started in `Head`.
- Move your `temp` to the node you want to delete (in this case one before the last: `temp->next == NULL`).
- Free the memory for `temp2`.
- Set the pointer of `temp->next` to `NULL`.
- Return the pointer to `head`.

Now this is not the only algorithm, there are a lot of ways you can accomplish this. The following code would be my solution to the function `del_p` (if you would want to delete the last node):

```
void del_p(struct Node *head)
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        struct Node *temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL) temp = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

You can make this code a little more general to make it possible to delete any Node, by passing a pointer to that node (or a value), the code would look as follows:

```
void del_p(struct Node **head, struct Node *delete_node)
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        struct Node *temp = *head;
        if (temp == delete_node)
        {
            *head = (*head)->next;
            free(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next != delete_node)
                temp = temp->next;
            if (temp->next != NULL && delete_node != NULL)
            {
                temp->next = delete_node->next;
                free(delete_node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you, this code isn't tested, but tell me if you have troubles!

Comment: According to the question we can only use the current pointer so we cannot use the head to traverse the list.

Comment: Oh, I see, in that way the easiest way to solve it is to use your code with a double pointer parameter, because in that way you modify the memory of the node on the list, not of a copy of it and set it to `NULL`.

Comment: "because as it is written right now it will only work if you hand in the pointer to the last node on the list." - Actually, his code works for every node *but* the last. The fact that he wasn't taking a reference to the pointer kept the node in the list. Also, the first example you show only deletes the last node (not sure if that's what you meant to do) and in the second example `head = head->next` doesn't affect the list and your `while` loop in the `else` branch doesn't protect against `delete_node` not being in the list (thus an infinite loop in that case).

Comment: Good but that condition should be `while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next != delete_node)`.